# Cannot generate signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

Since I incremented the `compileSdkVersion` from `22` to `23`, I cannot generate a signed APK.
Every time I try to generate the signed APK, I receive this error:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1

When I click on `Install Repository and sync project`, I get this error:

> Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-android-m2repository' Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install. Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.

Also, I have an internet connection.
I tried to update libraries using SDK Manager, and also restart Android Studio, but it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Where is your `build.gradle`? Where is your error?

Comment: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1  doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use a non-existent version of the support library. The latest version of the support library is 23.0.0, not 23.2.1.

Replace `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'` with `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'`.